# Show tableview scroll bars permanently

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Is there a way of showing the scrollbars of a UITableView all the time?

Comment: What's the use-case? This sounds like a non-standard UI and I can't think of a situation where this would be desirable.

Comment: The tableview is very small just to allow the user to select airports and it only 4 items are in view at a time.  The best I could do is put an icon below and above it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, the *UIScrollView* (of which *UITableView* is a subclass) doesn't support this.